# How to export numpy array to csv without including filename in file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, export-to-csv

I need to export a numpy array to csv without any headers or indices but every method I've tried has included the name of the file within the file itself.

So far I've tried

```
pd.DataFrame(array).to_csv('test.csv.gz', header=False, index=False, float_format='%d')
```

and the following :

```
np.savetxt('test.csv.gz', array, fmt='%d', delimiter=',')
np.savetxt('test.csv.gz', array, fmt='%d', delimiter=',', header=None)
np.savetxt('test.csv.gz', array, fmt='%d', delimiter=',', header='')
```

but no luck.

When I open the .csv file in iOS Numbers, there's the expected matrix in the usual rows and columns format, but in an unnumbered row all on its own is the filename and this is creating problems for the next step in the pipeline.

What can I do? Thanks.

Edit: Thanks for the first set of comments. What I'm doing with the csv file afterwards is putting it into Amazon SageMaker so I can create a model and endpoint. Here's the error that comes up with the csv file that's being generated:

ClientError: Non-numeric value 'w' found in the header line '�w��\�test.csv��K��8н�R�ȹ��zU@��gYɇ�`...' of file 'test.csv.gz'. CSV format require no header line in it. If header line is already removed, XGBoost does not accept non-numeric value in the data.

I used iOS Numbers to see how the csv file was being exported and what the problem might be. Thanks.

Edit2: Here's the top-left corner of the array.

```
np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Edit3: Output from .csv.gz in a text editor followed by the output from .csv

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: I don't know iOS Numbers, but if all rows are numbered and above all those is one unnumbered and it shows the filename - could it be possible, that  this is just the way Numbers tells you the name of the file which is printed below?

Comment: Yeah I agree with what @SpghttCd says - if your file is a .csv though you could physically go in in a text editor (or `cat` in terminal) and see if this filename line belongs to the file or the standard format of iOS numbers

Comment: Fair enough. The idea is to create a model and endpoint using Amazon SageMaker but when I try to do that, I get this error message:

"ClientError: Non-numeric value 'w' found in the header line '�w��\�test.csv��K��8н�R�ȹ��zU@��gYɇ�`...' of file 'test.csv.gz'. CSV format require no header line in it. If header line is already removed, XGBoost does not accept non-numeric value in the data."

Sorry for not putting this in the question.

Comment: What array.astype('int') returns?

Comment: It returns the same thing as array

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Could you please show the first lines or the dataframe: `print(pd.DataFrame(array).head())`

Comment: Err... have you tried not to add the `.gz` the the name of the file: `... .to_csv('test.csv', ...` instead of `test.csv.gz`?

Comment: I haven't but I'm confident that's not the issue. I'll try it anyway. 
PS. Added a segment of the array in the question.

Comment: Well, I'm completely sure that this is the issue. A compressed file is a binary format, which explains your symbols in the error message above. And if you look in the spec of the gzip format http://www.zlib.org/rfc-gzip.html#header-trailer, there's a pretty good chance to see the original filename as clear ASCII text in the header. So: leave away the `.gz` and it should work.

Comment: So far, leaving off .gz hasn't helped. And if it is going to help eventually, I need a way to do this using .gz as it reduces the size of the files by 1000-fold. Not only that, but a few months ago it worked with .gz. I don't know what's changed but I find it hard to believe that this fuctionality has been completely removed.

Comment: Please show the first lines of the `csv` file (the non compressed version, so without the `.gz` extension). And please use a simple text editor to load it (or the `head` command if you have it in a shell). I cannot imagine that the name of the file could be there...

Comment: I've switched to just using the top-left corner of the array to make things quicker. I first exported it as .csv.gz and then as .csv. I've pasted the outputs of both as shown in a simple text editor in the question above.

Comment: By the way, that's using numpy.savetxt()

Comment: I'm starting to think this is an issue on Amazon's side. I'll send them a message. Weird, because I swear this approach worked a few months ago.

Comment: With the .gz name `savetxt` gzip compresses the file.  You need to use a file viewer/user that handles that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shows:

```
'�w��\�test.csv��K��8н�R�ȹ��zU@��gYɇ�`...'
```

as the header line. The `\` character and the name of the file let think that the program is trying to process a gzip compressed file without first uncompressing it. Some systems have enough magic to transparently compress and uncompress files, some have not.

From their documentations, both `pandas.to_csv` and `numpy.savetext` automagically compress their output when they are passed a filename ending in `.gz`. This is even confirmed by your comment

> using .gz as it reduces the size of the files by 1000-fold

The problem it that when you try to load it into SageMaker, it tries to read it directly and chokes because the first bytes are not those of a (uncompressed) CSV file.

It may have worked if still *somewhere* in the processing chain, the file had been silently uncompressed. Many transfert tools are known to be able to compress/uncompress on the fly.

How to fix:

1. do not compress the file at generation time and ensure that it will never be compressed

or

2. do not change anything at generation time, but ensure that the file will be decompressed (`gunzip`) before being loaded in SageMaker

Comment: Thanks. There's a compression option in SageMaker for Gzip but when I try to use it it says "Invalid compression type for channel train: File mode only supports NONE, got Gzip instead" If I get it to work, I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help - you were absolutely right. The last time we did this, I did not realise but my colleague had unzipped the csv before uploading it to Amazon, that is why I didn't think that was the issue. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate the gzip feature of `savetxt`:

```
In [2]: np.savetxt('foo.txt.gz',np.arange(12).reshape(3,4))
```

Looking at the file as plain text we see the name:

```
In [3]: cat foo.txt.gz                                                                                                   
��\�foo.txt2�3���
```

Numpy's own loaders have no problem with these files:

```
In [4]: np.loadtxt('foo.txt.gz')                                                                                         
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
       [ 8.,  9., 10., 11.]])
In [5]: np.genfromtxt('foo.txt.gz')                                                                                      
Out[5]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
       [ 8.,  9., 10., 11.]])
```

I can explicitly un-zip this file and get a plain text csv:

```
In [6]: !gunzip foo.txt.gz | cat                                                                                         
In [7]: cat foo.txt                                                                                                      
0.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+01 1.100000000000000000e+01
```

I get the same thing if I save without a `gz` name:

```
np.savetxt('foo.txt',np.arange(12).reshape(3,4))
```